# Comparing numbers on multiple columns (Google Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a spreadsheet on google docs, listing prices of different products from different sources.

Then **I want to compare each of the product's price and format the cell background color where the product is cheaper** (my real problem here).

For now, it has 3 columns (B, D and F), from row 3 up to 18.
Each row is a product, and each column is a different "store".

I have searched for 2 hours now and I can't find anything close to this. Every question I found is about comparing an array to a single cell, not row to row, including multiple columns.

Is there a simple function or custom formula to do this?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) and search for functions for doing it x)

Comment: @werner when I said funtion I was refering to [spreadsheets built-in functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?rd=2), not scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Please try clearing formatting from and selecting ColumnsB:F and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... **Custom formula is** and:

```
=and(B1<>"",B1=min($B1,$D1,$F1))
```

Then select formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.